# Clicking button within span with no ID using Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium

I'm trying to have click a button in the browser with Selenium and Python.

The button is within the following

```
<div id="generate">
    <i class="fa fa-bolt"></i>
            <span>Download Slides</span>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Chrome's dev console tells me the button is within `<span>` but I have no idea how to reference the button for a `.click()`.

Comment: So you have to click on that `<span>` element?

Comment: When I right click and inspect element for the button that I click to submit it  links to that <span> element so i believe so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you just want to click on an element without an `id` or `name`, I'd suggest three ways to do it:

1. use `xpath`:

   ```
   driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="generate"]/span')
   ```
2. use CSS selector:

   ```
   driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#generate > span')
   ```
3. Just try `.find_element_by_tag_name()` like:

   ```
   driver.find_element_by_id('generate').find_elements_by_tag_name('span')[0]
   ```

   Note that this way first try to get the `generate` `<div>` element by it's `id`, and then finds all the `<span>` elements under that `<div>`.

   Finally, gets the first `<span>` element use `[0]`.